# Is this legal javascript? Passing arguments to function and having it change them

Tags: javascript, function, variables, arguments

Is this legal? And does it work in all browsers?

```
function func1(a, b, c) {
  //b == 2 here
  change_em(arguments);
  //b should equal 3 here
}

function change_em(args) {
  args[0] = 6;
  args[1]++;
  args[2] = [];
}

func1('foo', 2);
```

If you are wondering, I need to adjust the arguments in a function. A macro would be perfect, except javascript doesn't have one. Doing it properly, i.e. passing the variables to a function, then returning them in an object, and then extracting them in the caller would be almost as much code as just copy/pasting the adjuster function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is valid under EcmaScript 3 and EcmaScript 5 non-strict, but it is not valid under EcmaScript 5 strict mode.  It works in all modern browsers and most old ones.  It should not work in strict mode such as when run in Firefox 5 with a `"use strict"` directive.

From the [EcmaScript 5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6) section 10.6.11.c.ii

> 10.6 Arguments Object
>
> ...
>
> If strict is false and name is not an element of mappedNames, then
>
> 1. Add name as an element of the list mappedNames.
> 2. Let g be the result of calling the MakeArgGetter abstract operation with arguments
>      name and env.
> 3. Let p be the result of calling the MakeArgSetter abstract operation with arguments
>      name and env.
> 4. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of map passing ToString(indx), the
>      Property Descriptor {[[Set]]: p, [[Get]]: g, [[Configurable]]: true}, and false as
>      arguments.

Basically, the `arguments` object gets a setter for each index so that assigning to `arguments[i]` changes the value of the named parameter at position `i`.  There is language in the spec which makes it work vice-versa.

This should work in non-strict mode in any interpreter

```
(function (x) {
  alert("x=" + x + ", arguments[0]=" + arguments[0]);  // Both should be 0
  arguments[0] = 1;
  alert("x=" + x + ", arguments[0]=" + arguments[0]);  // both should be 1
  x = 2;
  alert("x=" + x + ", arguments[0]=" + arguments[0]);  // both should be 2
 })(0);
```

But if you run the above on Firefox 5 with a use strict directive you get different behavior:

```
(function (x) {
  "use strict";

  alert("x=" + x + ", arguments[0]=" + arguments[0]);  // Both should be 0
  arguments[0] = 1;
  alert("x=" + x + ", arguments[0]=" + arguments[0]);  // x=0, arguments[0]=1
  x = 2;
  alert("x=" + x + ", arguments[0]=" + arguments[0]);  // x=2, arguments[0]=1 
 })(0);
```

Comment: +1 but it would still be good to have some links to the standards that apply

Comment: @mike Wow that was quick! Awesome explanation too, some of us mortals need it. ;)

Comment: @James, yeah, the annotated HTML version of the spec is nicely done and easy to link into.

Comment: @mike so in the OP example it would have to use `arguments[1]` to reference `b` after the `change_em()` or set `b = arguments[1]` (For strict mode). Is that correct?

Comment: @James, in strict mode, there should be no way for `change_em` to change the value of `b` in `func1`'s scope.  One of the goals of strict mode was to get strict lexical scoping, so unless `change_em` is a closure inside `func1` (which it is not in the OP) it cannot change variables that are local to `func1`.  Note I said lexical scoping; proper block scoping will have to wait for http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:let

Comment: @mike is there are way of making a call time closure? i.e. I define a (global) function once, then call if from two different functions while having it be a closure to them? (Basically to avoid having code repetition, and writing the closure function twice.) I was thinking something like var new_func = global_func and have new_func have the same code as global_func but as a closure.

Comment: @Ariel, No.  There's no way to do such a thing except by using `eval` as a poor man's macro system.  `global_func_code = "(0, function (x) { return x + y; })"` then inside the function you want to contain `new_func` you do `var new_func = eval(global_func_code);`.  Note that the `0,` is there to get it to work around IE bugs that have to do with `eval` returning undefined when the top-level content could be considered a function declaration or function expression.

Comment: @mike i mean that in `func1` you'd have to re-assign the variables to see the new values.

Answer (score 1):

*See edit below – this doesn't apply to this question, but is still true:* In JavaScript, only complex types (objects and arrays) are passed by reference.  Primitive types (string, number, and boolean) are passed by value; changing a parameter would only affect that variable in the local function.

```
var primitive = 1;
var complex = { prop: 1 };

function func1() {
    change(primitive, complex);
    // primitive == 1
    // complex == { prop: 2 }
}

function change(a,b) {
    a++;
    b.prop++;
}
```

---

**Edit:** I missed that you are passing the `arguments` object.  [A quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/QVUyB/) yields the same results in Chrome 13, IE 9, Firefox 4, and Opera 10.62.

Comment: Please read my code again. I'm not passing a primitive type, I'm passing the arguments object.

Comment: @Ariel: Whoops, missed that; sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` is an array-like Object, but an Object nonetheless.  So when you pass it as a parameter to another function it will be passed by reference.  Thus when you mutate any values they will change in the original `arguments` object as well.  So this will work as you propose.  As far as I know passing objects by reference is supported in all browsers, however in EcmaScript 5 strict mode the arguments object index named properties are not dynamically mapped to the named formal parameters any more, so this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, where "all browsers" is a reasonable list of modern, Javascript enabled browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Because `c` was not passed in when calling `func1()`, it will not be included in the arguments. Therefor setting `args[2] = []` in `change_em()` will not also set `c` in the parent function.